# Segfault on copying struct

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, memcpy

I have a struct as following:

```
extern struct team_t
{
    char *name1;
    char *email1;
    char *name2;
    char *email2;   
} team;

struct team_t team =
{
    "some string1",
    "some string2",
    "some string3",
    "some string4"
};
```

Then in another file I create the following function that copies this struct into a new struct:

```
void *ucase( struct team_t *team)
{
  struct team_t *ucase_team = malloc( sizeof *ucase_team);

  memcpy ((char*)ucase_team, (char *)team, sizeof (ucase_team));

  return NULL;
}
```

However, when I want to call `ucase(team)`, I'm getting a segfault. I need to use `void *` because this will later be used for shell signals. What am I missing?

Update: Following call gives  `type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘struct team_t’)` error:

```
ucase(*team)
```

Update 2: I have removed Null return and used `ucase(team)` but still getting segfault.

Comment: `sizeof (ucase_team)` will just returns `size of pointer`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: You need to provide more code, e.g. show how you call your function. There's a few bugs in your current function (such as `sizeof (ucase_team)` in the `memcpy()` call should be `sizeof (*ucase_team)`, and you also return NULL so you leak memory) - but nothing that should cause a segfault, unless you have passed some invalid value to your `ucase` function. Please create a full example that can be compiled/run to showcase your problem.

Comment: Where in your code does it crash?

Comment: How `team_t` is defined? Show [mcve].

Comment: You know you have a memory leak there, don't you?  Oh, and the casts to `char*` are pointless in `memcpy()` call.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to use the return value of this function? Which is....

Comment: Please see my update. I have showed team_t structure and my call

Comment: Your update is inconsistent with the question. Decide what error you are having. And post [mcve].

Comment: `team` is a struct and cannot be dereferenced. What you need is `&team` instead of `*team`. But if you got a compile error, you cannot get a sefgault.

Comment: Ok, VTC for the lack of [MCVE].

Comment: If you'd be really doing C those cast when calling `memcpy()`  were useless. If the compiler insist on them you most likely are doing C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument of `memcpy()` should be `sizeof(struct team_t)` instead of `sizeof (ucase_team)` as `ucase_team` is a struct pointer variable. It can be either `sizeof(*ucase_team)` or `sizeof(struct team_t)`.

Also calling `team()` function like

`ucase(*team);`

is wrong as `team` is not a variable of pointer type, it's a normal structure variable. Probably you want

`ucase(&team)`;

Comment: Or just `sizeof *ucase_team` (which would then be visually consistent with the `malloc()` call).